# Chrome button black border

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome

I am getting a weird issue where Chrome is showing the current focus with a black border, which it has not done before. I am not sure if this is a settings issue or because of the latest update.

An example of this occurs when I click the number next to the like button on YouTube:

[image: bordered button example]

My OS is Kubuntu 20.04.